# Overloading code generators in Xtext

Tags: java, dsl, xtext

I have a very simple DSL that consists of a validator element that contains a list of comparators:

```
Validator:
  'validator' name = ID '{'
    comparisons+=Comparison*
  '}'
;

Comparison:
  LessThan | GreaterThan | EqualTo
;

LessThan:
  'lt' value = INT
;
```

With this I am trying to generate C code.  Where I loop through each validator, create a C file (based on the name of the validator) and place the comparators into a ternary conditional statement.  When I loop though each comparator it calls a definition for the class `Comparison` which outputs the `if` statement.  A cut down example (outputs something similar to CPPUNIT):

```c
int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  // parse argv[1] if it exists -> place into i
  printf("%c", i < (comparator_value_1) ? '.' : 'F');
  printf("%c", i > (comparator_value_2) ? '.' : 'F');
  printf("\n");
  return 0;
}
```

I can get all of this working nicely; however the problem I am having is that I seem to have to do a selection of conditionals within my `Comparison` generator.  I seem unable to override the generator by adding a handler for LessThan.

```
def compile(Comparison c) '''
  printf("%c",
    i «IF c.eClass.name.equals("LessThan")»...«ENDIF» «c.value»
      ? '.' : 'F');
'''
```

When I attempt to overload it:

```
def compile(LessThan lt) '''
  printf("%c", i < «c.value» ? '.' : 'F');
  ...
'''
```

The overloaded routines don't get called, which is at best unfortunate.

It is called by if this makes any difference:

```
«FOR c:v.comparisons»
  «c.compile»
«ENDFOR»
```

Where 'v' is the Validator.

Does Xtext have this ability?

Comment: Seems OK at first view. This is called polymorphic dispatch and should work with Xtext.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Xtext can use polymorphic dispatch (courtesy of @SpaceTrucker) in which:

> a function or method can be dynamically dispatched based on the run time (dynamic) type of more than one of its arguments.

In order to use this functionality I had to add one word to it `dispatch`.

```
def dispatch expandComparator(GreaterThan gt) '''
    printf("%c", i < «gt.value» ? '.' : 'F');
'''

def dispatch expandComparator(EqualTo eq) '''
    printf("%c", i == «eq.value» ? '.' : 'F');
'''

def dispatch expandComparator(LessThan lt) '''
    printf("%c", i < «lt.value» ? '.' : 'F');
'''
```

And use the following to generate it:

```
«FOR c:v.comparisons»
    «c.expandComparator»
«ENDFOR»
```

The name of the function had to change as `compile` was a single dispatch function.

The following link has more details on this solution.
http://dslmeinte.wordpress.com/2012/08/03/polymorphic-dispatch-in-xtend/